# Aggregate Function with Non-Aggregate Function In Select Command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exercising coding in MS.SQL Server. I have a small table below:

```
INV_NUM  INV_AMOUNT
-------  ----------
8000        235       
8001        312 
8002        528
8003        194
8004        619
```

I would like to write the query for all the invoices that will show:

- the invoice number,
- the invoice amount,
- the average invoice amount, and
- the difference between the average invoice amount and the actual invoice amount.

My code below:

```
SELECT I.INV_NUM,I.INV_AMOUNT,AVG(I.INV_AMOUNT) as AVERAGE,(AVG(INV_AMOUNT)-I.INV_AMOUNT) as DIFFER
FROM INVOICE I
GROUP BY I.INV_NUM,I.INV_AMOUNT;
```

The result in MS SQL did not generate the avg value, instead it shows INV_AMOUNT value in each row.

The result is :

```
INV_NUM  INV_AMOUNT    Average      Differ 
--------- ------------------------------------
8003     194            194            0
8000     235            235            0
8001     312            312            0
8002     528            528            0
8004     619            619            0
--------------- -------------------------------
```

I found if I have only one row in the table, it works fine.
Why this happened?  Thanks!

Comment: can you please show your output ?

Comment: @ZainArshad Hi, result added. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
select
  inv_num,
  inv_amount,
  avg(inv_amount) over() as average,
  avg(inv_amount) over() - inv_amount as diff
from invoice
```

Your query is grouping your rows as separate groups. Instead you need to use a window function over a single group (using `OVER`).

Result:

```
inv_num  inv_amount  average  diff
-------  ----------  -------  ----
8000     235         377      142 
8001     312         377      65  
8002     528         377      -151
8003     194         377      183 
8004     619         377      -242
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use different solutions. As The Impaler mentioned you can use window functions. For diving deeper into this way of implementation you should read some tutorials about that. 
Another way is using an CTE. You will first select the average invoice amount as own query. Afterwards you will use it in your "main" query. Looks like that:

```
WITH avg_inv AS
(
select avg(inv_amount) average
)
select
  inv_num,
  inv_amount,
  (select average from avg_inv) as average,
  (select average from avg_inv) - inv_amount as diff
from invoice;
```